# How to install NRPE in compute nodes of openhpc xcat diskless clusters?

Tags: installation, hpc, nrpe

I have small xcat diskless cluster in which I want to install NRPE on the compute nodes. How to install NRPE on the os image or chroot path of the management node that when the computes nodes are rebooted the image with Nrpe installed will be booted in the compute nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the breakdown steps

1. Copy `OpenHPC.repo` to your chroot environment.

```
cp OpenHPC.repo /install/netboot/centos7.9/x86_64/compute/rootimg/etc/yum.repos.d/
```

2. 

`yum --installroot=/install/netboot/centos7.9/x86_64/compute/rootimg install ohpc-base`

3.
`yum --installroot=/install/netboot/centos7.9/x86_64/compute/rootimg install nrpe-ohpc nagios-plugins-nrpe-ohpc`

Replace this `/install/netboot/centos7.9/x86_64/compute/rootimg` path with your chroot path

4. ...and then `packimage` and reboot your nodes